# SQL SUM a COUNT from an inner query

Tags: sql-server

How do I sum up a column from an inner query like this? Obviously this doesnt work but it is essentially what I am trying to do. There are a lot of similar posts to this but this is unique in that mine has a `HAVING` clause.

```
SELECT SUM(cnt)
FROM
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt
        FROM users
        GROUP BY email
        HAVING COUNT(*)>1
    )
```

Comment: I'm not clear as to what you are "essentially trying to do." Can you provide more background?

Comment: That would work fine if you gave an an alias for your inner query [see here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/83862/2)

Comment: @njk I'm trying to find the sum total number of records in the users table that have the same email address.

Comment: @ConradFrix I swear I tried that but I must have screwed something else up in the process. That worked! If you respond as an answer, I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wrote should work provided you have an alias for your query

```
SELECT SUM(cnt)
FROM
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt
        FROM users
        GROUP BY email
        HAVING COUNT(*)>1
    ) as t
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/83862/2)